# Excel formulas to convert between Western Arabic & Eastern Arabic numerals?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, arabic

I'm working on an Excel project that requires I convert between numbers as follows

```
1 <--> ١
2 <--> ٢
3 <--> ٣
4 <--> ٤
```

According to [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals) the ones on the left are called "Western Arabic" and the ones on the right are called "Eastern Arabic". So, put another way, I want formulas that convert between Western and Eastern Arabic numerals.

When I entered the first few Eastern Arabic numerals into a series of cells, I was able to drag down as usual to produce the others, as shown in cells E2:E16 below. But I need formulas for more advanced use.

[image]

Comment: You can use the following custom format: `[$-,206]0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following custom format: `[$-,206]0`

If you want to use a formula then:

```
=TEXT(A1,"[$-,206]0")
```

[image]

And back:

```
=--B1
```

[image]

Comment: How about going the other direction?  That is, I want to be able to convert both eastern to western and western to eastern.  Also could you explain a little how to use these custom formats - how did you come up with this?

Comment: `=--B1` should do that

Comment: I tested and found the @ScottCraner formulas to work. I wish I understood a little so that I could apply this knowledge rather than treating it like a blackbox -- but nevertheless, I appreciate the help very much.